# Permission error when using Vscode and SSH to code python on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, raspberry-pi, vscode-remote

So I'm trying to code a HiWonder MasterPi robot which is controlled by a Raspberry Pi using Vscode. I can use Vscode to ssh to the robot but when I try to code, and import HiWonder libraries which uses firmware with an pi adapter, I get Permission error: /dev/mem

The code runs fine when using VNC to run the file. So I'm assuming I need to have super user permissions: 'sudo' to run the python file from within Vscode.

So I have created a launch.json file to achieve this but now Vscode is looking for a debugging server which I do not seem to be able to connect to. Im not actually sure what a debugging server is?

Any help would be appreciated.

regards
Brad

Comment: You can try to run vscode as root or Change permissions for `/dev/mem`.

Comment: Ive changed permission for /dev/mem/ which is meant to be frowned upon but it did not work. 

When I ssh using VSCode, im using the root: 'pi' user, but no result.